# jquery template if condition rendered as comma in IE alone

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-templates

I am really struggling hard , does anybody have any idea why the following statement is being rendered as comma in IE

```
 {{if (true)}}
```

same as below one

```
{{/if }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `{{if true}}`

If you are using an observable that is not in an expression, then jQuery templates sees that it is a function and calls it as a function to get the observable's value. If it is in an expression, then this doesn't happen.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/998XL/)

Comment: This is some other code I am looking at it , but they are using something like this  $('#tableID').link(jsonObject,"#TemplateID") , what plugin do you think this is , i didn't see .tml , .appendto , instead of that they have this one